# Singular integral equation calculus of variation kernel

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations

How to solve this integral?
$$\int_{T-s}^{T}\frac{1}{t^n(T-t)^n}\mathbb{d}t, \qquad (n \in \mathbb{N})
$$
This integral type singular integral of order $n$. Please help me to solve or give some reference books.

Comment: Do you have a bound for $s$?

Comment: yes, for $s\in (T/2,T)$  and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is finite.

Comment: @kamalakkannan See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a process I have discussed in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082959), the integral can be converted to
$$I=\left(\frac 2T\right)^{2n-1}\int_0^{\theta_0}(\sin x)^{1-2n}dx$$
where $\theta_0=\arccos(1-\frac{2s}T)$. With your assumptions, the integral is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{x^{n}(T-x)^{n}} dx &= \frac{1}{T^{n}} \int \frac{1}{x^{n}(1-x/T)^{n}} dx \\
&= T^{1-2n} \int y^{-n} (1-y)^{-n} dy \\
&= T^{1-2n} \mathrm{B}_{y}(1-n,1-n) \\
&= T^{1-2n} \mathrm{B}_{x/T}(1-n,1-n) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-n} \frac{x^{1-n}}{T^{n}} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}(1-n,n;2-n;x/T)
\end{align}

We have used the [incomplete Beta function and Gauss's hypergeometric function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17).